# In Google AMP right way to print current year in the footer

Tags: amp-html

I know that, we are not allow to write any custom script tag in amp html page but i cannot find any kind of documentation or any way to write my little js code into amp html page but obviously it is necessary to write everytime this pitch of code into our footer. so i will anticipate that someone have any idea on that.

*Here you find our common code to get dynamic year*

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
```

Comment: Finally i got solution to this problem. here you go: 1. make a new, simple HTML page that only contains: 1. a simple html5 structure 2.the JavaScript  for setting the copyright and date. Insert this new HTML page into the correct position in the corresponding page via an amp iframe.

Comment: Here is my iframe code: <amp-iframe width="5" height="5" layout="responsive" sandbox="allow-scripts" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://www.arifkarim.com/landingpages/include/time/index.html">
        <amp-img layout="fill" src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/536538454_640.webp" placeholder></amp-img>
    </amp-iframe>

Comment: if your using php pages then you can easily use the <?php Date('Y'); ?> type code, as well.

Comment: yes, i had also tried that way but we are not allow to write php code on our  JSP pages..but anyway thanks

Comment: could you not do the same as in JSP code?? something like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_handling_date.htm

Answer (score 0):

AMP is very restrictive with javascript. Script tag is prohibited, except for loading amp-components or jason-formated states.

Otherwise only some javascript expressions that (re)define states. No access to global objects like window or document and only custom amp methods and events call with a special syntax (on:event). The specs for the amp-bind are a good overview (https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind).

BUT, there's a much simpler and elegant way than embedding html5 with js in an i-frame to achieve what you want: The amp-timeago component. By setting the date format (and why not, using it as state) and, maybe some @(media) css, you'll get what you want without placing a i-frame that will slow your page (event if it's an amp-iframe) and more in the "AMP spirit".
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-timeago

Hope this help

Comment: BTW The document.write() API is obsolete and considered harmful. You shouldn't use in any project. It is specifically mentioned as a reason for prohibiting third-party js in AMP
https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-how/
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/10/dont-docwrite-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JSP you should just render the date on the server before sending to the client.

At the top of your page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
```

In the body of your page:

```
&copy; <fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" />
```